# Putting any fields of referenced entity in lightbox frame

Tags: 7, views, entities

I want output a field as a link to an overlay that has fields of a referenced entity in it.
I can output the actual link just fine as long as it doesn’t have to be an overlay. 
Content type A is called ‘performance’, content type B is ‘performer’ (to which is being referenced).

So, for now, in my view there are only two fields: ‘Performer name’(of content type B also the title) and ‘title’ (of content type A). ‘Performer’ is arranged above ‘title’ and display set to none. ‘Title’ has ‘ouput field as link’ checked and has the token in the URL that is the title of ‘Performer’.

So this makes the link that is the title in the view go to the node of the performer that is referenced in the ‘Performance’ node.

I know that in the ‘rewrite results’ fieldset, I can fill in ‘lightbox2’ in the ‘rel’ attribute of my link. When I do this though, the lightbox shows, but is empty. No image, no values of any field, no nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doens't necessarily have to be done using lightbox. It ended up being a lot easier using a jQuery plugin like [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

I made extra fields in views and gave them a class the jQuery could latch on to using

```
$('hideMe').hide;
```

and using jQuery's `click();` method to go and say `(this).modal`

A different question here at Drupal Answers went into the same issue but it was more about how to write the jQuery code so definitely more of a jQuery question. Anyway the question with the exact code can be found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47850/comparing-a-clicked-views-row-in-a-loop).

Answer (score 0):

The rel attribute should be "lightframe". It is used for HTML elements you want to open in lightbox.