# Comparing a clicked views-row in a loop

Tags: 7, views, javascript

When I loop through my `.views-row` divs in jQuery, I need to 'grab' the one that is clicked on, needing to uniquely identify it and put only the selected fields from that particular div in my modal frame. Now I have the selected fields of all the divs within that loop in my modal frame.

I don't think I'm too far off with the following here below. I think the only thing that's missing is that I haven't been able to properly 'say' to drupal which `div` is being clicked and see to which `views-row-number` it corresponds to in order to display only that one in the modal frame.

obviously `jQuery(".views-row .views-row-" + index).click()` isn't the way but I'm sortof out of ideas which one that would be then.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

    row = jQuery(".views-row");

    row.each(function(index){
        forModal = jQuery('.forModal');
        forModal.hide(); 
        jQuery(".views-row").click(function(){

                if (jQuery(".views-row .views-row-" + index) ==
                                jQuery(".views-row .views-row-" + index).click()){
                                 forModal.modal();
                }

        }); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making that a bit harder than it needs to be...if I understand you right anytime a row is clicked you want to identify that row, extract a field from it and display it in a modal?

If so something like this would be a bit simpler:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.views-row').click(function() {
      // Find the modal within this row and show it.
      $(this).find('.forModal').modal();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Sorry if I've mis-understood what you're looking for, I wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: Not seeing any modalframe at all from this. I can't figure out what the declaration of $row is in your code and how it's supposed to be used. Definitely the `this` keyword I need to implement.

Comment: `this` will give you the element that's been clicked (i.e. the row with the `.views-row` class on it), and the `$()` just extends it to a jQuery object. I'm guessing there's an element within that row that you need to get hold of?

Comment: yes it's the elements with the class `.forModal` that are in some of the elements in my `views-row` that I need. `this` does return the div that I click indeed. jQuery really is snappy stuff.

Comment: It gets snappier ;) I've updated the answer, I think it'll work based on your last comment

Comment: Fantastic stuff. awesome. Works like a charm.